# Navigating between user controls in same form

Tags: c#, forms, visual-studio, navigation, user-controls

I have a windows form that allows different user controls to show and be hidden by different button.

I would like this user controls to communicate directly with each other and change values etc.

For example usercontrol1 below

[image]

User will fill form, then when they click Proceed, usercontrol1 should close and usercontrol2 should now be visible with user information picked and displayed  as follows

[image]

So far I have the code below

```
private void btnProceed_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string name = tbName.ToString();
        string email = tbEmail.ToString();
        string phone = tbPhone.ToString();
        string color = tbColor.ToString();

        this.Hide();

        UserControl2 u2 = new UserControl2();

        MainForm f1 = new MainForm();
        f1.panelMain.Controls.Add(u2);

        f1.listView1.Items.Add(new ListViewItem(new[]{
                            name,
                            email,
                            phone,
                            color}));
    }
```

It does not work. Only the usercontol1 is hidden and I'm left with a blank.
What I'm I doing wrong?

(Using visual studio 13 and c# language)

Comment: Because you are creating a new instance of MainForm and you add the new usercontrol to that instance. You will see it if you add _f1.Show();_. But I presume that you want to add the new usercontrol to the existing instance of MainForm

Comment: @steve Yes ....how would I add the control without creating the new instance of the MainForm?

Comment: In the simplest way you pass the instance of the current MainForm to the UserControl constructor, keep that instance stored in a global variable of the UserControl and use that instance when you need to switch the two usercontrols. This will be problematic to correctly handle for other tasks. I would recommend to redesign your application to let the MainForm decide which usercontrol to show when needed.

Answer (score 1):

You are adding the new usercontrol to a new instance of MainForm. You can't see it because this new instance is never shown. To avoid this problem in the simplest possible way you pass the instance of the current MainForm to the UserControl constructor, keep that instance stored in a global variable of the UserControl and use that instance when you need to switch the two usercontrols.

In MainForm.cs (when you create the first usercontrol)

```
UserControl1 uc = new UserControl1(this);
.....
```

In UserControl1.cs

```
public class UserControl1
{
   MainForm _current;
   public UserControl1(MainForm f)
   {
       InitializeComponent();
       _current = f;
   }
   private void btnProceed_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
   {
       .....
       UserControl2 u2 = new UserControl2();
       _current.panelMain.Controls.Add(u2);
       u2.listView1.Items.Add(new ListViewItem(new[]{
                        name,
                        email,
                        phone,
                        color}));
   }
}
```

This will be problematic to correctly handle for other tasks. I would recommend to redesign your application to let the MainForm decide which usercontrol to show when needed.

In this approach you use events to get informed in MainForm.cs when the user clicks the UserControl1, so you get this in MainForm.cs

```
UserControl1 uc = new UserControl1();
uc.UserClick += UserAdded;
.....
```

where UserAdded is a method of MainForm that received the info about the new user though the class UserInfoArgs

```
public void UserAdded(UserControl1 sender, UserInfoArgs args)
{
    sender.Hide();
    UserControl2 u2 = new UserControl2();
    this.panelMain.Controls.Add(u2);
    u2.listView1.Items.Add(new ListViewItem(new[]{
                        args.name,
                        args.email,
                        args.phone,
                        args.color}));
}
```

And in UserControl1 you add the delegate, the event and raise the event when you need to communicate to MainForm the info about your new user.

```
public class UserControl1
{
     public delegate void onClick(UserControl1 sender, UserInfoArgs args);
     public event onClick UserClick;
     ....
     private void btnProceed_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
     {
         UserInfoArgs args = new UserInfoArgs()
         {
             name = tbName.Text,
             email = tbEmail.Text,
             phone = tbPhone.Text,
             color = tbColor.Text
         };
         if(UserClick != null)
            UserClick(this, args);

}
public class UserInfoArgs
{
     public string name {get;set;}
     public string email {get;set;}
     public string phone {get;set;}
     public string color {get;set;}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think using **backgroundworker** control for this actually works for your case .

```
private void btnProceed_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string name = tbName.ToString();
    string email = tbEmail.ToString();
    string phone = tbPhone.ToString();
    string color = tbColor.ToString();

    string a = " "+name+" "+email+" "+phone+" "+color;

     backgroundWorker1.RunWorkAsync(a);//passing the variables to the backgroundWorker
}
```

And then in backgroundWorker_doWork(),you can populate the data you're getting as you like .

Answer (score 0):

You are overcomplicating things. You can just layer the two controls on your UI on the same position, and set the second control's `Visible` property to `False`.

Make the first user control expose an event for the button's click (or just expose the button so you can access its `Click` event), so that you can detect that mouse click from the main form. Then, when the listener for that button is called; the main form can get the data out of the first control, use it to initialize the second control, and then hide the first one and show the second one.